# Add timestamp to XML when parsing with PHP script

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am parsing a .csv file with a php script. The file requires a timestamp at the top of the file so they know when the file was generated. I am not sure how to put a simple timestamp next to where it says "generated="date"> on the second line. Everything else is working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products generated ="date">
<product>
    <stylenum>{$row['stylenum']}</stylenum>
    <upc>{$row['upc']}</upc>
    <url>{$row['url']}</url>
    <price>{$row['price']}</price>
    <currency>{$row['currency']}</currency>
    <available>{$row['available']}</available>
</product>
```

**Here is what the output should look like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products generated="2013-09-23T02:45:00">
  <product>
 <stylenum>c2260</stylenum>
 <upc>84493004xxxx</upc>
 <url>http://www.XXXXX.com/backpack-60-pack-medium-bodega</url>
 <price>328.95</price>
 <currency>USD</currency>
 <available>1</available>
</product>
```

What is the proper code to put the date there?

Thanks

Comment: Either your input and your output documents are **not** well formed.

Comment: You're probably looking for some XML library that can be used to manipulate an XML Document like http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic - Or perhaps on how to format a date string: http://php.net/date - It's not so really clear from your question what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a timestring and populate it to the xml, just like the other variables.

Add the following code on top of the xml generating code:

```
$date = date('c');
```

And then in the xml:

```
<products generated ="$date">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tdate = new DateTime('NOW');
$datereplacedxml = str_replace('date', $tdate, $xmlfile);
```

Or event better:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlfile);

$tdate = new DateTime('NOW');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//products[@generated="date"]');
$element = $elements->item(0);
$element->setAttribute('generated', $tdate);
```